# Speeding up a procedure for checking equality of two variables

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, markov-chains

I am trying to implement a Markov Decision Process in Python and having some troubles with speed when running the following code (to no surprise...):

```
def p(j, state, action):
    if (np.linalg.norm(j[0,:]-np.array([-100,-100]))>0.1 and np.linalg.norm(state[0,:]-state[1,:])<0.1):
        return 0
    elif (np.linalg.norm(j[0,:]-np.array([100,100]))>0.1 and np.linalg.norm(state[0,:]-np.array([5,1]))<0.1):
        return 0
    elif (np.linalg.norm(j[0,:]-np.array([100,100]))<0.1 and np.linalg.norm(state[0,:]-np.array([5,1]))<0.1):
        return 1
    else: ....... (here other stuff follows but this isnt the issue)
```

The function is supposed to give me the probability, given that I am in the state (`state`), to transition to a state (`j`), using an input (`action`), which it does correctly, yet slowly.

Currently, I need to loop twice over the variables `j` and `state` which are 2 by 2 arrays. Ideally, I would be able to figure out how to write such a function which inputs NOSTATES x 2 x 2 arrays, where NOSTATES is the number of states.

I guess I should try to vectorize my code, but unfortunately, I am not sure how to implement the equality checks then.

Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: A typical input to `p()` would be:

```
j=np.array([[1,1],[3,3]]) state =np.array([[1,2],[2,3]]) action = [0,1]
```

Comment: Why do you have a `return`? Are you mapping this function over the array?

Comment: I'm not overfly familiar with markov-chains but I suspect you're mapping this function, which unnecessarily considers the entire array... and runs in Python time.

Comment: @roganjosh Currently no. The function eats 3 arrays and outputs a scalar. Ideally, it should eat 2 vectorized array and a normal array and output the corresponding vectorized quantity.

Comment: You are probabily correct to assume so. I'd be interested to know how I implement the if-statements in a vectorized setting. This I think is what hinders me

Comment: Arrays are not "vectorized"/"normal". You mean you have an array of object type?

Comment: You use `np.where()`, typically, to apply a vectorized filter to the array, but I suspect we're missing detail here. Please can you add a small example input and output and show how this all fits together?

Comment: Well, OK, I'm not overly familiar with the lingo here, sorry. What I mean is that it currently takes 2 by 2 np.arrays as input. Here a 2 by 2 array corresponds to a particular "state" of the system. Given that the system has NSTATES, I would like it instead to apply to arrays of dimension NSTATES by 2 by 2.

Comment: Sorry, my last comment wasn't meant to be a pop at you; rather, your understanding of the term might be hindering your search to make this more efficient.

Comment: No offence taken! I'm from another community and to efficiently ask questions here I recognize that it is my job to speak your language.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the edit. I understand the problem now. I'll have a think but it might not be something I can answer meaningfully.